# SFTP from CentOS to Windows CANNOT connect

Tags: linux, windows, centos, ssh, sftp

I'm configuring a SFTP access from a linux machine (client) to a windows 2012 machine (server).

On server side I'm running coreFTPServer configured for FTP over SSH only and with key auth only. Using the coreFPT client on my windows laptop I can establish a connection successfully. Instead, while using the same network and credentials, I cannot connect through the linux client.

I use the following, the key is not encrypted with a passphrase:

```
sftp -i .ssh/priv -P 22 -vvv configured_user@server_ip
```

and I get the following output, with debug at level 3 (I hided ip and username):

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.135.150.2" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <server_ip> [<server_ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file .ssh/priv type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file .ssh/priv-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version CoreFTP-0.3.3
debug1: no match: CoreFTP-0.3.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to <server_ip>:22 as '<configured_user>'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file ".ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file .ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <server_ip>
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,rijndael128-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes256-ctr,rijndael128-cbc,rijndael192-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,none
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,none
debug2: compression ctos: none,none
debug2: compression stoc: none,none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 4082/8192
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:g1vBYrOo0avwG21dmFm6I6XDA+B4eepZC6+h80TH+XY
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file ".ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file .ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from <server_ip>
debug1: Host '<server_ip>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in .ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 4070/8192
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to <server_ip> port 22: invalid argument
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

The issue seems to be coming from ssh:

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to <server_ip> port 22: invalid argument
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

but I couldn't be able to identify the cause, I tried with several keypairs, generated both from client side with ssh-keygen (RSA and DSA) and server side with CoreFTPServer (I prefer to generete them client side though and then trade only the pub key).

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to check port 22 with telnet? It's opened?

Comment: Yes it is opened, I can connect with other machines

Comment: I am unfamiliar with your windows based ssh server, as I bet many others are too.  Can you provide more information about this program?

Answer (score -1):

`sftp -i .ssh/priv -P 22 -vvv configured_user@server_ip`
https://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp

none of the options you pass to sftp are valid,
the options you are passing are valid for `scp` or maybe `ssh`

try using `scp`
https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

Comment: The man pages you're looking at are as old or older than what RHEL/CentOS 6.x currently has. All the options look good for a modern OpenSSH `sftp`.